# function for shuffling a deck of cards js

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'm trying to build a Black Jack game and moving forward to a function where it is supposed to shuffle the cards, I was struggling a bit just to make a proper 'shuffle' and ended up looking online. I did find some code that does what I want, but there is no reference to what it does exactly, could someone help?

```js
const shuffleDeck = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    let shuffle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (deck.length));
    let temp = deck[i];
    // here it assigns the iterated elements to newly created temp.
    deck[i] = deck[shuffle];
    // here uses the shuffle variable on the iterated deck[i]?
    deck[shuffle] = temp;
    // assigns the shuffled deck to temp? What does temp do after??
  }
};
```

I have already managed to create the 52 cards deck, so I'm just going step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function loops through the array, and on each iteration switches the current element with an element on a random position ( choosen here: `let shuffle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (deck.length));`). The `temp` variable is just used to make the value switch between the 2 values.

Say you have two values stored in variables `A = 1` and `B = 2`, to switch the values between the variables you would need a third variable, since there is no way to change them without losing the value of either, so these are the steps:

```
// save one of the values to a temp variable (we save A)
temp = A
// Put the value of B in A (after this step A = 2 and B = 2
// if you hadn't saved the value of A you would have lost it )
A = B
// then restore the value that was in A to B
B = temp
// you don't care about the value of temp after this... just that A and B are now switched
```

This is equivalent to this part of your code:

```
let temp = deck[i];
deck[i] = deck[shuffle];
deck[shuffle] = temp;
```

When you do this for every element in the array it's sort of guaranteed the array should be shuffled

### Simpler way for switching variables

It is possible in javascript to switch variables in one instruction without a temp variable like this :

```
[a, b] = [b, a]
// for arrays switch element in position i with position j
[array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
```

So an easier way to shuffle would be to

```
 //loops throug each card
 for (let i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    // picks the random number between 0 and length of the deck
    let shuffle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (deck.length));
    
    //swap the current with a random position
    [ deck[i], deck[shuffle] ] = [ deck[shuffle], deck[i] ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an image below showing visually what this code is doing, essentially it is going through every index, choosing a random other index, and swapping the values. This wont ever add or remove values, just quite literally shuffle them around.

The blue arrow represents the current index i, green arrow represents the variable current.

[image: Visualization of the shuffle function]

The blue arrow then moves to the next index and repeats until its through the entire deck.

Answer (score 0):

The temp variable is just there as a placeholder to swap the position of two cards. Think about having a glass of milk in a blue cup and a glass of coffee in a red cup. You want to put coffee in a blue cup and milk in a red cup.

You will take a green cup (temp) and put milk inside the green cup, then put coffee in a blue cup (where milk was), and finally put milk from the green cup in a red cup.

```js
 //loops throug each card
 for (let i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    // picks the random number between 0 and length of the deck
    let shuffle = Math.floor(Math.random() * (deck.length));
    
    //uses 3 buckets method to swap cards
    let temp = deck[i]; //holds one card in temp variable
    deck[i] = deck[shuffle]; 
    deck[shuffle] = temp; 
  }
```